# Why is wrong when I use original `str`?

Tags: c++

I want to Know that why this first block is right? And the second block is wrong?

```cpp
    vector<string_view> split(const string & str, char target) {
        vector<string_view> res;
        string_view s(str);
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < s.size()) {
            while (pos < s.size() && s[pos] == target) {
                pos++;
            }
            int start = pos;
            while (pos < s.size() && s[pos] != target) {
                pos++;
            }
            if (pos > start) {
                res.emplace_back(s.substr(start, pos - start));
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

```cpp
    vector<string_view> split(const string & str, char target) {
        vector<string_view> res;
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < str.size()) {
            while (pos < str.size() && str[pos] == target) {
                pos++;
            }
            int start = pos;
            while (pos < str.size() && str[pos] != target) {
                pos++;
            }
            if (pos > start) {
                res.emplace_back(str.substr(start, pos - start));
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

The wrong answer when I input "Are You Okay":
[wrong answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe1zp.png)

I don't know how is it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the "wrong" *and* the "right" answer by copy pasting text instead of linking to images.

Comment: Why do you assume `substr` does the same thing?

Comment: substr of basic_string_view returns basic_string_view not temporary string that is why first example works.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Where is the UB? All I can see is the dangling views, but `str` is passed by reference, so it still exists after return and the views still point into it, which might be intentional (lightweight)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) returns a new string, not a view. But I see now in Sam's answer that I was wrong about the first version, didn't know `std::string_view` has it's own `substr()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    s.substr(start, pos - start)
```

`s` is a `std::string_view`. In this version, `std::string_view::substr` returns a `string_view` of a data that's owned by the underlying `str` that gets passed in as a parameter to this function.

```
    str.substr(start, pos - start)
```

`str` is the original `std::string` that gets passed in. In this version, calling `substr()` on the original `std::string` returns a new `std::string`.

As part of evaluating this expression, a `string_view` gets created on the string that belongs to the returned `std::string` object.

The returned `std::string` object is used temporarily, solely in this expression. Therefore, at the conclusion of the expression the `std::string` that's returned from `std::string::substr` gets automatically destroyed.

The `string_view` on the string that belonged to the temporary `std::string` object now becomes invalid, and all subsequent use of it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I think maybe when I use str.substr to string_view, which will create a temporary object from string to string_view. The temprary object will be desroyed. Is right?

Comment: `str.substr()` returns a new object. What this object is used for is immaterial. It is a new object. You can certainly get a `string_view` out of it, if you wish, but that `string_view` is using the new object's actual string, so when the new object gets destroyed, your new `string_view` is worthless.